# Как отсортировать таблицу начиная с определенного значения?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Подскажите, как правильно отсортировать такую таблицу?

Нужно вывести сначала то, где есть `|2|`, а после все остальные:

```
id - data
1  - |1|2|3|
2  - |3|
3  - |2|
4  - |1|3|
```

Должно быть такое:

```
1  - |1|2|3|
3  - |2|
2  - |3|
4  - |1|3|
```

Нужно под `CodeIgniter`.

Пытался так делать `$builder->orderBy('data="|2|"', 'ASC');`, но не работает.

Comment: `ORDER BY LOCATE('|2|', data) DESC`

Comment: @Akina, подскажите, а как это преобразовать в такую конструкцию `$builder->orderBy( );` ?

Comment: Вероятно, `$builder->orderBy("LOCATE('|2|', data)", "DESC");`...

Comment: @Akina, выдает ошибку, mysqli_sql_exception #1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'DESC, "data") DESC' at line 3

Comment: Может, фреймворк не понимает сортировки по выражению? ну попробуйте `$builder->orderBy("LOCATE('|2|', data) = 0", "ASC");`

Comment: @Akina, я нашел решение, практически случайно, протестировал и работает отлично)) Прикрепил ответ, может вдруг кому то понадобится

Answer (score 1):

Нашел решение.

```
$builder->orderBy("CASE WHEN data = '|2|' THEN 0 
  WHEN data LIKE '|2|%' THEN 1 
  WHEN data LIKE '%|2|%' THEN 2 
  WHEN data LIKE '%|2|' THEN 3 
  ELSE 4
END, data", 'ASC');
```